# VBA macro returning runtime error '5'

Tags: vba, excel

So I've been pondering at this silly little thing I wrote to update a large worksheet (trimmed it for testing) for a while now, but I'm not seeing where I made a mistake. It seems to break on line 6 but I'm not sure why.

Just FYI, it seems to work fine if I replace headers in the table with specific dates and DateDiff with Format (It actually works wonderfully elsewhere). This time-saving piece became a time sink of its own, sigh...

```
Sub UpdateData()

Dim myWeek As String
Dim myOh As String
myOh = DateDiff(W, "01/01/2017", Date)
myWeek = "Week " & myOh
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Range("A6:A8").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Range("Table2[[#Headers],[Week 10]:[Week 62]]").Select
    Selection.Find(What:=myWeek, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate


    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0)).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: *" time-saving piece became a time sink of its own, sigh..."*, yes, because you neglected the #1 time saving piece, aka `Option Explicit` :)

Comment: I still suck badly at all this, just learning from grounds up :(

I'll note it for the future though! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed the Interval argument enclosed in quotation marks as below. The way you had it was looking for a variable called W

```
Sub UpdateData()

Dim myWeek As String
Dim myOh As String
myOh = DateDiff("W", "01/01/2017", Date)
myWeek = "Week " & myOh
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Range("A6:A8").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Range("Table2[[#Headers],[Week 10]:[Week 62]]").Select
    Selection.Find(What:=myWeek, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate


    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0)).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```